# java.lang.IllegalStateException on Tomcat 7.0.2 but working fine on WAS7

Tags: java, jsf-2, tomcat7, websphere-7, illegalstateexception

I have this application on `Websphere Application Server 7.0` that I am in process to port to `tomcat 7.0.2`.

I have following line of code in my application :

```
parameters.remove("MainUserId");
parameters.remove("MainPassword");
```

This code gives me the following exception on Tomcat

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No modifications are allowed to a locked ParameterMap
    at org.apache.catalina.util.ParameterMap.remove(ParameterMap.java:211)
    at com.csc.fs.accel.ui.action.admin.user.UserAccess.updateUser(UserAccess.java:1386)
    at com.csc.fs.accel.ui.action.admin.user.UserAccess.doPost(UserAccess.java:1775)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Basically here `parameters` is a session parameter map. So as per java specification parameters map is immutable. But this works good for Websphere Application server.

While researching, I read a comment [here](http://grokbase.com/p/tomcat/users/113ha3smr8/caused-by-java-lang-illegalstateexception-no-modifications-are-allowed-to-a-locked-parametermap) that says

> if this worked in WebSphere then WebSphere is not following the
>   specification. Either because of a bug or because it has been
>   explicitly configured to ignore that part of the spec.

Any alternatives? except *do not remove elements from map*

Also, is it possible if there is any configuration in tomcat that can make the parameter map `mutable` ?

Comment: Do you really need to remove those attributes from the parameter map?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza : yea I have to. :/

Comment: What if you just stop using them, or maybe there's a third party library/framework that handles this map (and the unwanted attributes) for you that is a black box for you (you can't modify it)?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza : Sorry, I dint quite get what you just said.. :) Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza : Thanks for the response. Just stop using these attributes is not a solution for me, I have to remove these, because If I do not remove them from the map, the map gets bigger and bigger and it severely hamper the performance. Also, you can not explain much about coding practices to a team of stakeholders who are stuck on the fact that "_this code worked on Websphere, So make it work on Tomcat_" , its like deliberately smashing your head on a wall (:D)  . So I am looking for like a workaround.

Comment: I totally understand that you can't give lot of technical explanations to the final client (it's a PITA). Maybe you can find where these attributes are set and try to stop sending them in the first place.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25610/discussion-between-mukul-goel-and-luiggi-mendoza)